# How to apply image transitions in Adobe after effects CS4?

Tags: adobe, after-effects, cs4

I am creating a video in which I need an image to fade in at a particular time and fade out at a particular time. The preset I want to use is "CC image wipe" under transition menu in the 'effects and presets' tab. How to apply the transition into the image such that it fades in and out in a given time range?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my own question.
Applying any transition or animation preset in Adobe After Effects CS 4 can be done by simply clicking, dragging and dropping the desired effect on the layer in which you want to see the change. The key to a successful transition is using key-frames. key frames do not appear on the screen while editing but if you click on the layer and press 'U' key twice, you'll see all the presets that you have applied on the layer in front of you. Next you need to click on the stopwatch icon on the desired transition or animation preset and drag a particular key-frame to the point from which you wish to start the transition and then increase the completion percentage and drag the second key-frame to the end of the transition point. RAM preview to see the effect.